# Bijective Proof - partitions

Tags: integer-partitions

what is a bijective proof of #93 in the link provided http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/bij.pdf:

> The number of partitions of $n$ with $k$ parts equals the number of partitions of $n + \binom{k}{2}$ with $k$ distinct parts

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: the paragraph that starts at the end of p. 4 of that PDF essentially gives the desired bijection.

Comment: sorry that is the wrong link. The correct link is http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/bij.pdf and it is question 93.

Comment: Edited the link, made the question a quote.

Comment: Fixed the link, which didn't work as given. My previous comment stands: the notes at the original link give the desired bijection. It includes a picture illustrating the idea, which @Thomas has given in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_1\leq a_2 \leq a_3 ... \leq a_k$ is a partition of $n$ then $a_1 < a_2+1 < a_3+2 <... < a_k + {k-1}$ is a partition of $n+0+1+2+...+k-1 = n+\binom{k}{2}$

Comment: Thank you! i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I am going to partition $5$ into three parts. How I do it below will give an indication of the bijection you can use.

There are two such partitions. Arrange the numbers in nondecreasing order:

$\color{blue}{5=3+1+1}$

$\color{brown}{5=2+2+1}$

Now, leave the last number in each partition alone, add $1$ to the number before that, add $2$ to the number preceding the one to which you added $1$, and so on  until you have added $k-1$, in this case $3-1=2$, to the first element. You find that your partitions of $5$ are mapped into two distinct partitions:

$\color{blue}{5+(2+1)=(3+2)+(1+1)+1}$

$\color{brown}{5+(2+1)=(2+2)+(2+1)+1}$

Note that $2+1=\binom{3}{2}=\binom{k}{2}$

$\color{blue}{5+\binom{3}{2}=8=5+2+1}$

$\color{brown}{5+\binom{3}{2}=8=4+3+1}$

The addition process is invertible, so we have bijected the two three-way partitions of $5$ into the two distinct three-way partitions of $8$.

Can you work from there?

For another bijective proof in partition theory, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4327857/248217).